# ASP.NET MVC - FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() and RolesIsUserInRole - wierd behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, roleprovider

I have something like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, false);
var tmp = Roles.IsUserInRole("administrator");
var _tmp = Roles.IsUserInRole(user, "administrator");
```

`tmp` is always false, and `_tmp` is always true. Why is `tmp` false?

Comment: What is your role provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are doing this during a login action, it's safe to assume the user is not logged in yet, and thus the `User` on `HttpContext` (accessible from your controller via `this.User` or just `User`) is set to an unauthenticated principal. `Roles` will use the current `User.Identity.Name` to get the username and retrieve roles, so in this case, you'd want to use the second overload.

If you need to use the first overload for some reason, you'd have to update user:

```
User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user, "forms"), new string[0]);
```

Normally, the FormsAuth module would update the `User` appropriately the next time the user visits a page after logging in, by reading the auth ticket cookie, decrypting it, and creating a new `GenericPrincipal` with a `FormsIdentity` using the name found in the ticket.

Answer (score 2):

`var tmp = Roles.IsUserInRole("administrator");` is checking if the currently logged in user is in the role while `var _tmp = Roles.IsUserInRole(user, "administrator");` is checking if `user` is in the role, whether or not they are logged in at the time.  And since `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, false);` won't take effect until the next request, `user` isn't actually loggen in yet.

Comment: And if i would want him to be logged in immediately, then how could i do that?

Answer (score 1):

SetAuthCookie only sets the cookie.  It does not log you in, nor does it load any of the user information.

The cookie is read on the next request, and then ASP.NET will configure the roles and identity as part of the request processing pipeline.

You can bypass this, but it essentially means duplicating the asp.net authorization code, all for one request.  It's probably easier to just redirect the user and reload the page.